# Tilting sine function to get countably infinite nonregular values?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$. A nonregular value $y$ of $f$ is any value such that not all $x \in f^{-1}(y)$ are regular. A point is regular if the Jacobian at it is surjective, in this case, has rank one.

If we tilt the map $f(x) = \sin x$ by some angle about the origin then the resulting map has countably infinitely many nonregular values.

My problem is: I don't understand why this is the case.

> Please could someone give me some geometric insight into why tilting
>   the sine functions yields nonregular values?

It seems to me that the untilted sine function has just as many nonregular values: The Jacobian is the derivative $J(x) = \cos x$ which vanishes infinitely many times...?

I am thinking about this because of the following text I read:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that without the tilting, all of the zeros of the derivative satisfy $\sin(x) = \pm 1$.  Thus, even though there are infinite points $x$ with $f'(x) = 0$, the only nonregular **values** (referring to elements of the codomain rather than elements of the domain) of $\sin x$ are $\pm 1$.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you. I was thinking of nonregular *points*.